# Apache RewriteRule does not work with forward slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect [website]/purchase/configure/quotation/ to [website]/purchase/index.php. I place an .htaccess file in [website]/purchase/ with the following rule:

```
RewriteRule "configure/quotation/?$" "index.php" [NC,L,QSA]
```

But it does not work. After many trials and errors, I found that the following rules work:

```
RewriteRule "quotation/?$" "index.php" [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule "/quotation/?$" "index.php" [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule "configure(.*)quotation/?$" "index.php" [NC,L,QSA]
```

But these do not:

```
RewriteRule "configure/quotation/?$" "index.php" [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule "e/quotation/?$" "index.php" [NC,L,QSA]
```

Apparently, the character /, if preceded by another character, is not properly processed. If it is not preceded (as in "/quotation") or if it's processed as any character (as in "(.*)"), the rule works fine.

This is driving me crazy. :-)

I'm using Windows 10, Apache 2.4.39, and https.

Comment: could you try setting the `RewriteRule "configure/quotation/?$" "index.php" [NC,L]` rule in an htaccess file at the root directory `[website]/` of your server instead of `[website]/purchase/` ? just to check

Comment: No change. Note that the .htaccess in the /purchase/ directory works, it's just that any rule that explicitly involves a `/` sign is ignored.